# Grep multiple strings from text file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Okay so I have a textfile containing multiple strings, example of this -

```
Hello123
Halo123
Gracias
Thank you
...
```

I want grep to use these strings to find lines with matching strings/keywords from other files within a directory

example of text files being grepped -

```
123-example-Halo123
321-example-Gracias-com-no
321-example-match
```

so in this instance the output should be

```
123-example-Halo123
321-example-Gracias-com-no
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Well I know that if I use " Grep -rhI "Halo123" . " then it would output any lines containing Halo123 within the current directory.. but I need to know how I would do it for multiple keywords :).

Comment: @Cyrus forgot to tag

Answer (score 11):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

> `-f FILE`: Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.

Output:

```
123-example-Halo123
321-example-Gracias-com-no
```

Comment: How do I set exact string? so like string has to match "Halo123", as if line contains example, 123-example-Halo it will class that as being a match and output, yet it didn't contain "Halo123"

Comment: I suggest to add option `--line-regexp` to `grep`.

Comment: I understand that the OP wants to do a literal match. You better add `-F`.

Comment: `--line-regexp` is perhaps not suitable here. The OP seems to look for substrings in the file to be searched.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look at the manpage for grep to get a better understanding of what options are supported by the grep utility. However, there a number of ways to achieve what you're trying to accomplish. Here's one approach:

```
grep -e "Hello123" -e "Halo123" -e "Gracias" -e "Thank you" list_of_files_to_search
```

However, since your search strings are already in a separate file, you would probably want to use this approach:

```
grep -f patternFile list_of_files_to_search
```

Comment: got error " list.txt invalid range end " & " list.txt unmatched [, [^, [:, [. or [= "

Comment: The patternFile must contain a list of regular expressions/patterns.

Based on the error message you posted, it sounds like one or more of the 'patterns' contains some regular expression metacharacters but doesn't form a valid regular expression. Please post the offending pattern(s) , without that, it's impossible to tell what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions for your question:

1. Use multiple regular expressions - a regular expression for each word you want to find, for example:

   ```
   grep -e Hello123 -e Halo123 file_to_search.txt
   ```
2. Use a single regular expression with an "or" operator. Using Perl regular expressions, it will look like the following:

   ```
   grep -P "Hello123|Halo123" file_to_search.txt
   ```

**EDIT:**
As you mentioned in your comment, you want to use a list of words to find from a file and search in a full directory.

You can manipulate the words-to-find file to look like `-e` flags concatenation:

```
cat words_to_find.txt | sed 's/^/-e "/;s/$/"/' | tr '\n' ' '
```

This will return something like `-e "Hello123" -e "Halo123" -e "Gracias" -e" Thank you"`, which you can then pass to `grep` using `xargs`:

```
cat words_to_find.txt | sed 's/^/-e "/;s/$/"/' | tr '\n' ' ' | dir_to_search/*
```

As you can see, the last command also searches in all of the files in the directory.

**SECOND EDIT**: as PesaThe mentioned, the following command would do this in a much more simple and elegant way:

`grep -f words_to_find.txt dir_to_search/*`

Comment: i need to run keywords/strings from a .txt file, also need to search for matches from files within a folder, not just a single .txt

Comment: @user3255841 Edited my answer to match your clarified question.

Comment: `sed` accepts files -- `sed 's/....' words`. But what is it for anyway? `grep -E 'aaa|bbb' /some/path/*`? Or `grep -f words.txt /some/path/*`.